# "Passato" or "passati"

Tags: gender, grammatical-number, agreement, auxiliary-verb, past-participle

In a translation exercise for «forty years passed» the correct answer is

*quarant'anni sono passati*

but if I understand correctly, the past participle for *passare* is *passato* and it doesn't need to be conjugated. So why *passati* instead of *passato*?

Comment: that is very clarifying. grazie mille

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exercise is correct: when making the composite tenses of intransitive verbs having *essere* as their auxiliary verb, the participle has to agree with the subject.

So, for instance:
* *È passato un anno.*
* *È passata una settimana.*
* *Sono passati tre anni.*
* *Sono passate tre settimane.*

Or,
* *Luigi è andato a casa.*
* *Maria è andata a casa.*
* *I due amici sono andati a casa.*
* *Le due amiche sono andate a casa.*

With transitive verbs using *avere* as their auxiliary, the situation is different: the participle definitely doesn't agree with the subject, and is in general in the masculine singular, but under some conditions it agrees with the object.

So:
* *Luigi* (or *Maria*, or *I due amici*, or *Le due amiche*) *ha/hanno mangiato la bistecca.*

But:
* *L'ha mangiato Luigi* (talking about a masculine singular *pesce*).
* *L'ha mangiata Luigi* (talking about a feminine singular *bistecca*).
* *Li ha mangiati Luigi* (talking about masculine plural *pesci*).
* *Le ha mangiate Luigi* (talking about feminine plural *bistecche*).

Comment: The concordance in the case of *avere* is typically used when the direct object precedes the verb; more generally, when the number or gender are determined by something that precedes the verb: *ne ha mangiati due* (speaking, say, of *cioccolatini*).