# Why "passata" instead of "passato" in "L'ambulanza non sarebbe passata"?

Tags: gender, grammatical-number, agreement, auxiliary-verb, past-participle

"Passata" is not even in the conjugation table:  listed [passare conjugation](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ItVerbs.aspx/%22passare%20conjugation%22).

Comment: Even though this question has received a good answer, I vote to close it, because it's been answered before. Read [here](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/present-perfect-when-do-we-need-to-change-the-gender-and-number-of-the-past-par), [here](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5142/passato-or-passati) and [here](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/54/past-participle-and-changing-endings-with-auxiliary-verb-avere). BTW, two of the three questions are yours, so practically you keep asking the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Italian when a verb is conjugate to a compound tense and the auxiliary verb is "essere" (to be) the past participle has to agree with the subject in gender and number.

The past participle of "passare" is "passato" *in the masculine singular form*, but since the ambulance is a feminine noun in italian the participle needs to be declined to the feminine singular version, which is indeed "passata".

Comment: Hm, thanks. But what about this one:non l'averebbero guardata morire. It used auxiliary verb avere. I remember it probably has something to do with the pronoun before the verb? Would you clarify it?

Comment: That is a different rule. When the auxiliary verb is "avere" and **the object is before the verb** the participle needs to agree with the object (note: not the subject!).

Comment: Note for example "non avrebbero guardato morire la donna". In this case the object is *after* the verb and so there is no agreement

Comment: Wow, italian is so complicated. Thank you so much!

Comment: @jxhyc also in "non l'avrebbero guardata morire", "guardata" denotes that who is dying should be a girl/woman, while with "guardato" should be a boy/man. That's because of the past participle verb part gender.